# Remove all lines with only one dot character

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a huge text. I want to remove all lines with only one `.` in it.

Sample input:

```
abc.google.org
yahoo.com
abc.yahoo.in
abcd.bing.com
abcd.xyz.bing.uk
abcd.xyz.mnp.bing.uk
stackexchange.com
yas.sxs.sxs.zs.sxstackexchange.com
```

Expected output:

```
abc.google.org
abc.yahoo.in
abcd.bing.com
abcd.xyz.bing.uk
abcd.xyz.mnp.bing.uk
yas.sxs.sxs.zs.sxstackexchange.com
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: There's probably a duplicate somewhere. You can use `grep` to look for lines with 2 or more `.` or use `awk` to split on `.` and select lines with at least three fields.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 8):

```
awk -F'.' 'NF!=2' infile
```

not print those lines if that was containing only two fields (i. e, line with only a single dot was found). field separator can be specified with the `-F` option.

---

or using the gsub() function:

```
awk 'gsub(/\./, ".")!=1' infile
```

if number of successful replacements of the dot character (with itself) was other than one occurrence, print it.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```bsh
grep -v '^[^.]*\.[^.]*$' input.txt
```

Print all lines that do *not* match a RE that looks for a single period in a line.

Comment: Use `-x` and we can then drop the line beginning and ending assertions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my sed solution, which uses the same regular expression as @shawn's grep:

```
sed -i.bak '/^[^.]*\.[^.]*$/d' FILE
```

It has the (dubious) advantage of working directly on the FILE (but it does write  a FILE.bak with the original content). The regular expression takes a full line thanks to its anchors ^ and $. If this line consists of a string with zero or more non-dots `[^.]*`, followed by a single dot, followed by zero or more non-dots `[^.]*`, it will be deleted.

Tested with the sample input.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at it is that you want the lines with at least 2 dots (assuming you don't want the lines with no dots). So:

```
LC_ALL=C grep '\..*\.' < input > outpu
```

Answer (score 2):

POSIX sed:

- Line with at least two dots print n Next.
- What remains are line with exactly one or none dots. Of these, delete the dot carrying.

```
sed -e '/\..*\./b' -e '/\./d' file
```

---

GNU awk:

- remove everything except dots and record the length of this resulting string and compare against one.

```
awk 'length(gensub(/[^.]/,"","g",t=$0))-1' file
```

---

GNU sed:

- store line in hold space for later use.
- Try removing a dot.
- if you failed, print line and next read.
- In case no dot remained => exactly one dot in original. So delete it.
- Else, retrieve the original line as it had > 1 dots.

```
 sed -e 'h;s/\.//;T;//!d;g' file
```

---

Perl:

- When the number of dot transliterations is one then assign the list separator($,) whose default value is empty string.
- the -p option will autoprint the current record.

```
perl -pe 'y|.||-1||($_=$,)' file
```

---

Python:

- list comprehension  along with an if clause to select those lines that split into two or more or none fields.

```
python3 <<\eof
with open('file') as f:
  print(*[l for l in f if len(l.split('.')) != 2],sep='',end='')
eof
```

---

Standard grep in which multiple -e statements signify ORing

```
$ grep -e '\..*\.' -e '^[^.]*$' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'print if tr/\.// > 1' data
```

Or

```
perl -F/\\./ -nle 'print if @F > 2' data
```

Comment: or maybe `tr/\.// != 1` since they only mentioned removing lines with one dot, though they didn't make it at all clear what should be done with completely dotless lines.

Comment: Of course, but the sample data given shown domain names and domain names without dot aren't possibile.